# Commit button greyed out when merging in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since today, when doing a merge, the "Commit" button in VSCode is greyed out for me (see below screenshot). Committing via the command line works just fine, so it seems to be a VSCode issue.

Note that this is specific to committing a merge. Committing code normally still works fine.

VSCode Version: 1.72.0 on Mac

Anybody else got the same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: the issue has since been closed as of the second [recovery update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is:issue+milestone:%22September+2022+Recovery+2%22+is:closed) for September 2022, presumably the bug has been fixed.

---

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162927) on the Visual Studio Code repository that seems similar, although the user reported it occurs after resolving a merge conflict (though I don't think that is actually relevant, it seems to just be for merges in general based off the commit to fix it).

This seems to be a regression that is [slated to be addressed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/162927#issuecomment-1272845806) in the recovery update:

> Apologies for the inconvenience. This is a recent regression and will be fix in our recovery release later this week.

[This](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/163159/files) is the actual change that was made for this.  Thus, the recovery update for 1.72 should fix this.

Comment: I've just started to see this old issue in VS Code (all projects). Workaround is to right click a file and select 'Stage Changes' (and hoping I don't bump the 'Discard Changes' option)